# Каким образом перемещаться по спрайту быстро?

Tags: css3

К примеру есть иконка спрайт на 1000 единиц , ведь найти иконку скажем 724 `background-position` будет весьма сложно , есть ли способы для обнаружения позиции нужного sprite ? [sprite demo](http://bayguzin.ru/demo/sprite/)

Comment: Поясните, о какой сложности идет речь, как найти `background-position` для иконки с порядковым номером 724.

Comment: сложности нету , но интересует то что в заглавие вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас фиксированное положение спрайтов, то можете на сервере или на клиенте сделать таблицу иконок по номерам, но в CSS такого способа нет